# MySql - объединение 2-х таблиц с условием

Tags: mysql

Вопрос такой, как можно объединить две таблицы:

Пользователи - `userstbl`:

```
user_id | name
1         Олег
2         Вася
3         Миша
4         Петя
```

Данные - `datatbl`:

```
id | user_id | data | month  
1       1       33       4
2       3       15       4
3       4       30       4
4       3       20       5
5       1       35       5
6       2       12       5
7       4       35       5
```

Мне надо получить все данные из первой таблицы и из второй за 4 месяц. Привести к такому виду:

```
user_id | name  | data
1         Олег      33
2         Вася      null
3         Миша      15
4         Петя      30
```

Пробую варианты с левым соединением `SELECT * FROM userstbl LEFT OUTER JOIN datatbl USING (user_id);`  - но не пойму как задать условие для выборки месяца `WHERE month IN (4)` - не подходит,т.к. пропадает пользователь с `user_id` - 2 Вася, а мне надо чтоб был виден весь список.

С уважением,
Дмитрий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `LEFT JOIN` таким образом:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, d.data
FROM userstbl u
LEFT JOIN datatbl d
ON u.user_id = d.user_id AND d.month = 4
ORDER BY u.user_id
```

Вот пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb2595f/2)